# Problems implementing swagger in C#

Tags: c#, rest, swagger

I've created the following webservice:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all users from CRS that are not included in the emaillist
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="emailList">string with emails separated by semicolon</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/user/getwurusersnotinlist/")]
    [SwaggerOperation("UserGetWurUsersNotInList")]
    public List<UserDto> GetWurUsersNotInList([FromBody] string emailList)
    {
        var list = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        var exclude = (emailList??string.Empty).ToLower().Split(';').ToList();

        return WurUsers
            .Where(user => string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Email) && !exclude.Contains(user.Email.ToLower()))
            .Select(user => user.Dto())
            .ToList();
    }
```

As you can see I'm trying to use the [FromBody] Swagger attribute here. On the client side the following code is used to retrieve the user data:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var semi = string.Empty;

        foreach (var user in students)
        {
            sb.Append(semi).Append(user.EMail);
            semi = ";";
        }

        var excludeList = sb.ToString();

        var crsUsers = UserServiceClient.UserGetWurUsersNotInList(excludeList);

        foreach (UserDto crsUser in crsUsers)
        {
            ...
        }
```

The problems with this code are:

1. The emailList is always null
2. The list read from the Request.Content contains the list minus the first 4 characters. Very strange.
3. When the result returns I get an exception saying 'unable to deserialize the response'. Inner: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   Looks like the code is sending an XML where a JSON is expected.

=== EDIT ===

Here's the generated code from Swagger at the client side:

```
    // Code generated by Microsoft (R) AutoRest Code Generator 0.16.0.0
// Changes may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if the code is
// regenerated.

namespace WUR.BBCourseEnrollment.Business
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Microsoft.Rest;
    using Models;

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public partial interface IWurCrsWeb : IDisposable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The base URI of the service.
        /// </summary>
        Uri BaseUri { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets json serialization settings.
        /// </summary>
        JsonSerializerSettings SerializationSettings { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets json deserialization settings.
        /// </summary>
        JsonSerializerSettings DeserializationSettings { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Subscription credentials which uniquely identify client
        /// subscription.
        /// </summary>
        ServiceClientCredentials Credentials { get; }


            /// <param name='customHeaders'>
        /// The headers that will be added to request.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name='cancellationToken'>
        /// The cancellation token.
        /// </param>
        Task<HttpOperationResponse<IList<UserDto>>> UserGetAllWithHttpMessagesAsync(Dictionary<string, List<string>> customHeaders = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));

        /// <param name='emailList'>
        /// </param>
        /// <param name='customHeaders'>
        /// The headers that will be added to request.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name='cancellationToken'>
        /// The cancellation token.
        /// </param>
        Task<HttpOperationResponse<IList<UserDto>>> UserGetWurUsersNotInListWithHttpMessagesAsync(string emailList, Dictionary<string, List<string>> customHeaders = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));

        /// <param name='customHeaders'>
        /// The headers that will be added to request.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name='cancellationToken'>
        /// The cancellation token.
        /// </param>
        Task<HttpOperationResponse<IList<ScheduleDto>>> UserGetSchedulesWithBlackboardIdWithHttpMessagesAsync(Dictionary<string, List<string>> customHeaders = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));

    }
}
```

Comment: The consuming code is not making an HTTP request.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean with 'Does not make an HTTP request'? The code is generated using the 'Add REST client' and using the Swagger file I downloaded from the webservice site

Comment: Then maybe it is... that code is not included

Comment: Added the client side code

Comment: Did you try ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) ?

Comment: The ConfigureAwait(false) did not help. After solving the XML JSON problem I got Ambiguous references to JsonSerializerSettings (1 in the generated code and 1 in the NewtonSoft assembly). I've stopped using Swagger all together. It is too unstable.

Comment: My comment is a bit confusing. Where I said Swagger I had to say SwashBuckle.